# Set default value Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-database

I need to set a date to Enddate if the user didn't enter it by taking the value from `Starting` input,
Let's say I have this Model:

```
class DataSet(models.Model):
Event     = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True ,null=True)
Starting   = models.DateField()
Enddate   = models.DateField(blank=True ,null=True)
Times     = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=4,blank=True ,null=True)
postdate    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
author      = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
def __str__(self):
    return self.Stating
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-Enddate',)
```

and the form is;

```
class DataSet_F(forms.ModelForm):
Event    = forms.CharField(label='Event')
Starting = forms.DateField(label='Start date',widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'type':'date'}))
Enddate  = forms.DateField(label='End date',required =False,widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'type':'date'}))
Times    = forms.IntegerField(label='Time',required =False)
class Meta:
    model= DataSet
    fields=['Event','Starting','Enddate','Times']
```

How I set `Enddate` equal to `Starting`  when the user didn't enter the value, then set `Times` equal to 1.
Many thanks

Comment: First of all I strongly recommend you to learn about Python naming convention. Your field names are all wrong. And to answer your question, your best option is to do it in the template with the help of a little JavaScript.

Comment: You could use form validation to raise an error. Or, before saving the DataSet object after the form is valid, you could set Enddate to Starting. Or you could use Javascript on the front-end to set these values before the form is submitted based on events.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it was so easy :)

```
class PostCreateEVENT(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = DataSet
template_name = 'Home/EVENTS/Add_event.html'
form_class = DataSet_F
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    if form.instance.Enddate:
        pass
    else:
        form.instance.Enddate=form.instance.Starting
        form.instance.Times  =1
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

THANK YOU ALL FOR MOTIVATION

Answer (score 0):

I also Found another way directly in the form

```
class DataSet_F(forms.ModelForm):
     Event    = forms.CharField(label='Event')
     Starting = forms.DateField(label='Start date',widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'type':'date'}))
     Enddate  = forms.DateField(label='End date',required =False,widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'type':'date'}))
     Times    = forms.IntegerField(label='Time',required =False)

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataSet_F, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.fields['Enddate']:
           pass
        else:
           self.fields['Enddate']=self.fields['Starting']
           self.fields['Times']  =1
    class Meta:
       model= DataSet
       fields=['Event','Starting','Enddate','Times']
```